# How using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in angular2

Tags: angular

I have simple angular2 application. The application has only one component with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.
The problem is the component never refresh its view.
How to make the component refresh itself after data array updated?
Here the code. I'm using Angular 2.0.0-rc.4.

index.html

```
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<app style="width:100%;height:100%;">Loading...</app>
</body>
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppComponent } from "./app";
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.ts

```
import {Component, ComponentRef, ComponentFactory, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";
import {ListComponent} from "./list";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Angular2 - app</h1>
      <gm-list></gm-list>
    </div>
    `,
    directives: [ListComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

list.ts

```
import {Component, Input, NgZone, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "gm-list",
    template: `<div style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
    List
    <div *ngFor="let item of data" >
        <div>
            {{ test }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.visible"> {{ item.name }}
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ListComponent {
    private _data: any = [];

    constructor(private zone: NgZone, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        var me = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            me.data = [
                { id: 1, name: "one", visible: true },
                { id: 2, name: "two", visible: false },
                { id: 3, name: "three", visible: true },
                { id: 4, name: "four", visible: false },
                { id: 5, name: "five", visible: true },
                { id: 6, name: "six", visible: true }
            ];
        }, 3000);
    }

    @Input() set data(data: any) {
        this._data = data;
        console.log("databind");
    }

    get data(): any {
        return this._data;
    }

    get test(): string {
        //console.log("test");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4746#issuecomment-150754049

> `OnPush` will only trigger change detection when an input property has
>   been changed as the result of a change detection check

1) So you need to run changes manually via `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck` like:

```
export class ListComponent {
    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.data = [...];
            this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        }, 3000);
    }
    ...
```

**[demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lhrnScqnN6GWXguUWp6v?p=preview)**

2) If you change input data on parent it will be updated because this will trigger the check for the child (**[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oVKpzkVnuKzp4CatVjpd?p=preview)**):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<gm-list [data]="data"></gm-list>`,
  directives: [ListComponent]
})
export class App {
  data:any[];
  constructor() {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.data = [...];
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

3) Or you can run updates by using reference to parent component(or by using `EventEmitter`) like this:

```
export class ListComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => App)) private parent:App) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
          this.parent.data = [...];
      }, 3000);
    }
}  

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<gm-list [data]="data"></gm-list>`,
  directives: [ListComponent]
})
export class App {
  data: any[];
}
```

**[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/d5h6FCUSDiy4eTncsdLb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is unstable yet. And code may be changed in releases. The solution below was found for version rc4.

1) add

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

2) after component state changed call

```
this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```